# I installed Mint 18 on my HP NV79 laptop, I can't use the mousepad

Tags: linux, proprietary-drivers

I can't use the mouse pad, and I am sure, there are other things I just haven't gotten to them yet. I have an HP NV79 laptop that I installed Linux Mint 18 Sarah on.

Comment: It is very difficult to know what pointing device a HP NV79 has, which makes it harder to help.  To resolve that, start a terminal and enter `cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep mouse -C5`. Copy/paste the output into your question above.